# Gmail "view original email" syntax

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

What's the identifier below in brackets signify?

"Received: from [831853863423] named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with". Trying to get better understanding of the syntax

I'm a novice, so don't know where to start?

Answer (score 0):

When you run through the entire message header using this [tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/) it appears to be a hostname that was sent to gmailapi.google.com similar to the screenshot below.

[image]

This information only appears whenever an email was sent using [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) `Method user.messages.send`